# Process.Start Catch all FileName/Arguments code

Tags: c#

I have some code that I wanted to improve. It uses Process.Start and should be able to handle any input any argument, and still work. 
I don't think I have covered all the bases. Can anyone suggest a better/more thorough approach?

ToMaybeUri is an extension method that tries to create a Uri.

ToValidMailToArgument is an extension method that adds "attachments="

IsValidEmail is an extension method that does a RegEx on the email address.

```
 public static void RunProcess(string fileName, string Params)
    {
        var useProcessStart = true;

        var validFile = false;
        var validDir = false;
        var validEmail = false;
        var validURL = false;

        var proc = new Process();
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        info.Arguments = Params;

        //try catches here in case the syntax of the string has invalid characters for dir/file
        try
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(fileName);
            validDir = di == null ? false : di.ExistsNow();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        try
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            validFile = fi == null ? false : fi.Exists();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        if (Params == "")
        {

            if (validFile)
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpper() == ".CHM")
                {

                    var helpProvider1 = new HelpProvider();
                    helpProvider1.HelpNamespace = fileName;

                    Help.ShowHelp(Application.OpenForms[0], helpProvider1.HelpNamespace);

                    MessageBox.Show(msg);

                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (validDir)
            {
                //skip
            }
            else if (fileName.IsValidEmail())
            {
                validEmail = true;                  
                info.FileName = "mailto:" + info.FileName;
                info.Arguments = "";

            }
            else if (fileName.IsValidUrl())
            {
                validURL = true;
                info.FileName = fileName.ToMaybeUri().Value.ToString();
                info.Arguments = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fileName + " does not exist.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //and has params
            if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpper() == ".PDF" && Params.ToLower().StartsWith("p"))
            {
                int pageNum = 0;
                string pageNumString = Grazer.Utilities.Strings.Right(Params, Params.Length - 1);
                int.TryParse(pageNumString, out pageNum);

                //PDFLocation = "/A \"page=" + pageNum + "=OpenActions\" \"" + ssGlobals.ssStartDir + "\\Example.pdf\""
                string app = GrRegistry.GetApplicationFromExtension(".PDF");

                if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(app).ToUpper() == "ACROBAT" || Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(app).ToUpper() == "ACRORD32")
                {
                    string PDFLocation = String.Format("/A \"page={0}=OpenActions\" \"{1}\"", pageNum, Path.GetFullPath(fileName));

                    info = new ProcessStartInfo(app);
                    info.Arguments = PDFLocation;
                }
            }
            else if (fileName.IsValidEmail())
            {
                validFile = false;

                try
                {
                    var fi = new FileInfo(info.Arguments);
                    validFile = fi == null ? false : fi.ExistsNow();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }

                info.FileName = String.Format("mailto:{0}{1}", fileName, new FileInfo(info.Arguments).ToValidMailToArgument());
                info.Arguments = "";                  
            }
        }

        if (useProcessStart)
        {
            proc.StartInfo = info;

            try
            {
                if (validURL || validFile || validDir || validEmail)
                    proc.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Message)
                {
                    case "No process is associated with this object.":
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show(ex);
                        if (info.Arguments.ToEmptyIfNull().Length > 0)
                            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} could not be opened with parameters: {1}", info.FileName, info.Arguments));
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} could not be opened", info.FileName));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you don't want to swallow exceptions.  On your catch blocks, make sure you're doing something after catching an exception.  Also, find out what specific exceptions can be thrown by methods you're calling in your try blocks and catch those specific exceptions, like so:

```
try
{
    SomeMethod();
}
catch (SpecificExceptionType1)
{
    //do something based on what this exception means
}
catch (SpecificExceptionType2)
{
    //ditto here
}
catch
{
    //handle unexpected exceptions here
}
```

Also, this smells suspiciously like homework - perhaps implementing a command shell?  If so, retag it as homework.  If not, just tell me to stuff it.